# Proof of existence and uniqueness of solution to f(c)=0

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis, path-connected

I have a function $f:R^n_+\rightarrow R^n$ for which I want to show the following:

$$\exists c\in R^n_+ \quad \forall i,j\,\,f_i(c)=f_j(c)$$
Where $f_i (c)$ are the different coordinates of $f$.

$f$ has the following properties:

1. $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial c_j}>0 \Leftrightarrow i=j$, furthermore the partial derivatives are never $0$.
2. $\lim_{c_i\rightarrow \infty} f_i(c) = \infty$
3. $\lim_{c_j\rightarrow \infty} f_i(c) = A_i$, $A_i$ here does not depend on $j$ (and of course $j\neq i$).
4. $\forall t\in R_+ \quad f(c) = f(t\cdot c)$

For $n=2$ this is very easy, basically just the intermediate value theorem. For higher dimension it gets more complicated. The idea is the following: If there does not exist such a $c$, then the image of $f$ is contained in $R^n-\{x\in R^n|x_1 = x_2\cdots=x_n\}$, which is topicologically different from $R_+^n$ (the preimage). All we have to show is something like we have a circle around this line, that can't then be contracted.

A bit more formally:
We define $\tilde{e}_i = [1,\dots,1,1/\epsilon,1,\dots,1]$, where $1/\epsilon$ is at the position $i$. 
With these points we have $f(\tilde{e}_i)\approx [A_1, A_2, \cdots, B_i,\dots,A_n]$, with $B_i$ being a huge number. We can then define path $p_{ij}:[0,1]\rightarrow R_+^n$, $p_{ij}(t) = t\cdot \tilde{e}_i +(1-t)\cdot \tilde{e}_i$. Then we connect all the path $f(p_{ij})$. These path will then from a closed path "around" the removed line $\{x\in R^n|x_1 = x_2\cdots=x_n\}$. This path could not be contracted if this line were not in the image of $f$. Therefore we have at least one such point.

Questions:

1. Does simply connected suffice also for higher dimensions or do I need algebraic topology?
2. Is there a way to proof that this point is unique?
3. Is there a more beautiful way to proof this? In its current version it's quite a mess.

Comment: Conditions 2 and 4 are incompatible; let $\{\mathbf e_k\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. By 2 and 4, $$f_1(\mathbf e_1)=f_1(2^n\mathbf e_1)=\lim_nf_1(2^n\mathbf e_1)=\infty$$

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan The standard vectors are not allowed, as they contain non positive entries ($c\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$). Basically assumption 4 is why only positive vecotrs are allowed.

Comment: 1. Why *algebraic* topology? Is your $f$ algebraic? 2. Do you have an example of such an $f$? 3. Quoting from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space : "The image of a simply connected set under a continuous [or even entire analytic -- I.P.] function need not be simply connected. Take for example the complex plane under the exponential map: the image is C - {0}, which is not simply connected".

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan The following functions proof, that 2 and 4 are not incompatible: $f_i (c) = \frac{c_i^n}{\Pi_j c_j}$

Comment: Not so sure about algebraic topology. I had a class of algebraic topology about 3 years ago or so. I thought that algebraic topology includes the extension of simply connectedness. My functions are not algebraic.
In my commet to Meisman there is an example of $f$.
3. That might be a problem. Is it true, that the image of a injective function will be simply connected, when the preimage is simply connected? Because my $f$ can be made injectiv, by assuming $c_1$ = 1.

Comment: In the limits in 2 (resp. 3) are the coordinates $c_l$ of $c$ just assumed fixed for $l\neq i$ (resp. $l\neq j$) as $c_i\to\infty$ (resp. as $c_j\to\infty$) ? Or are those limits uniform in $c$?

Comment: @PietroMajer They are assumed to be fixed. I guess uniformity of these limits would be inconsystent with 4. ( just intuition, without any deep thoughts).

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak are these assumptions 1,2,3,4 really the only features of your maps, or are there possibly other ones? To conclude some uniformity is needed, for instance on the behavior of $f$ on the boundary of

$$\Delta_\epsilon:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \forall i  \ x_i\ge\epsilon , \sum_{i =1}^nx_i=1\}.$$

Can you e.g. assume that $f_{|\Delta\epsilon}$ is uniformly close (or "not too far") to a multiple of the identity map etc?

Comment: @PietroMajer My functions are essentially growthrates of species in biology, so you can assume that they do not behave very weird (however I never put mathematical terms to "very weird"). They are potentially $C^\infty$. I do however not really understand what you mean by uniformly close.

Comment: Uniform close = close in the uniform distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm

Comment: I put it in another way: it would be useful   knowing something on $f(x)$ for x in the *boundary* of $\Delta_\epsilon$, that is, at least one coordinate of x is $\epsilon$. The assumptions tell  us something when x is a vertex of $\Delta_\epsilon$, and the behaviour is in the right direction to get the result, as you wrote in the post, but I'm not sure if it is enough.

Comment: On the boundary of $\Delta_\epsilon$ $f(x)$ will have at least one coordinate that is close to $A_i$

Comment: let's focus on the case n=3. By 4 it is sufficient to consider $f$ on the open equilateral triangle  $\Delta:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3: \forall i\,   x_i>0, x_1+x_2+x_3=1$. For small $\epsilon$,  $\Delta_\epsilon\subset \Delta$ is a closed equilateral triangle a bit shrunk. By 2 and 3 we know that f sends each vertex of $\Delta_\epsilon$ close to the corresponding axis, e.g $f(\epsilon,\epsilon,1-2\epsilon)=f(1,1,1/\epsilon-2)$ is close to the third semi-axis,  $(0)\times(0)\times\mathbb{R}$ (that is, the first two coordinates are bounded, the third is large).

Comment: We need to know what is the behaviour of f on the three edges of $\Delta_\epsilon$: does f send the edge $[V_1,V_2]$ of the triangle to a curve close to the angle bounded by the first and the second axes? I'm not sure, maybe yes, thanks to the assumptions on the partial derivatives. Here if "close" is "close enough" then a linking argument (or topological degree, or even Brouwer fixed point theorem) should be sufficient for the existence.

Answer (score 1):

Put $\mathbb{R}^n_0=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\sum_ix_0=0\}$, and let $\pi\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n_0$ be the orthogonal projection.  You have a map $f\colon(0,\infty)^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and we can define $g\colon\mathbb{R}^n_0\to\mathbb{R}^n_0$ by 
$$ g(x) = \pi(f(e^{x_1},\dotsc,e^{x_n})). $$
You want to show that $0$ is in the image of $g$, and the only way you can realistically hope to do that is by proving that $g$ is surjective.

If you want to use methods of algebraic topology, the main thing that you need to check is that $g$ is proper, or in other words that the preimage of any compact set is compact.  Your differential conditions are probably designed to do that; I am not sure whether they succeed.  Anyway, it is probably better to go back to whatever context you were looking at, and see whether you can prove properness directly.

If $g$ is proper, then it has a unique continuous extension $g_\infty\colon\mathbb{R}^n_0\cup\{\infty\}\to\mathbb{R}^n_0\cup\{\infty\}$, and $\mathbb{R}^n_0\cup\{\infty\}$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^{n-1}$, so the $(n-1)$'th homology group is $\mathbb{Z}$.  This means that $g_\infty$ acts on that homology group as multiplication by some integer $d$, called the degree.  If $d\neq 0$ then $g_\infty$ (and thus $g$) will be surjective.

If your differential conditions on $f$ ensure that the Jacobian of $g$ is nowhere zero (and you also have properness) then $g$ will be a covering map and you will have $d=\pm 1$.

Suppose instead that you can find a point $b$ such that

- $g_\infty^{-1}\{b\}$ is some finite set $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_r\}$
- The Jacobian of $g_\infty$ at $a_i$ is not zero for any $i$.

Let $d_+$ be the number of $a_i$ where the Jacobian is positive, and let $d_-$ be the number of $a_i$ where the Jacobian is negative.  It can then be shown that $d=d_+-d_-$, so if $d_+\neq d_-$ then $g_\infty$ will be surjective.

Comment: Thanks, seems promising. I have however some questions:
1. There's a typo in the definition of $\mathbb{R}_0^n$, the sum should go over $x_i$.
2. I assume the usual combinations of proper functions are still proper, is this correct?
3. I only have to show, that $g$ is proper and that it's Jacobian vanishes nowhere, then the theorem is proven, correct?
4. Do you have any recommendation where I could read this up and possibly cite?